# How to import a Chrome extension's files from 6 years ago (I have the session data!)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, local-storage, appdata

In 2016, I would backup all my Chrome extension's current session data (the directory looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6NCj.jpg)). I copy-pasted these files for few computer transfers and it worked every time - it got my extensions up and running fine. It meant I could transfer extension settings and other local data without losing or have to recreate the old settings (think Reddit Enhancement Suite and how you lose your username tags, upvote tallies, and toggled settings every time you move computers).

I haven't tried doing an Extension transfer for a few years, but wanted to transfer the 2016 session data of an extension onto my new Chrome install. Unfortunately I can see that Chrome has actually changed the way they save local extension files.

The old way to replace Chrome session data comprised of replacing just two files (a .localstorage and .localstorage-journal file) and the steps were the following:

- Open Windows Explorer
- Go to: %localappdata%\google\chrome\user data\default\Local Storage
- Replace the "chrome-extension_[extension key].localstorage" and "chrome-extension_[extension key].localstorage-journal" files
- Open Chrome again and extensions have old session data transferred

Now instead of just two files saved locally for current session data, there's a maze of multiple folders and I can't find the .localstorage and .localstorage-journal files anywhere. It seems that somewhere down the line (around 2019?) Chrome converted these .localstorage files into maybe .json or other files?

Is there a way to convert the data from these old file extensions into whatever the new format is?

Let me know if none of this makes sense or if you need elaboration. The specific extension data I want is from a Chrome extension called Sidewise, and I had a lot of cool windows and tabs saved in the local data.

Comment: You could perhaps use a Google Account with Chrome’s sync ([link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10248834?hl=en)).

Comment: @harrymc unfortunately chrome doesn't sync local settings :/ regardless, I want to open the session data from 2016 that I had saved for this one app, so I need to get the data from these specific files anyway.

Comment: You could try [LocalStorage Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/localstorage-manager/fkhoimdhngkiicbjobkinobjkoefhkap) to export on source and import on target. Also, copying your entire user profile will get you everything.